# Relational table with perl dbi module

Tags: perl, foreign-keys, dbi

I'd like to make a relational table with perl between this two tables and insert in it data :

```
$create_query = qq{
    create table article(
        id_article int(10) auto_increment NOT NULL,
        url MEDIUMTEXT COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
        html_extr_text TEXT COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
        concord_file TEXT COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
        sys_time VARCHAR(50),
        primary key (id_article)
        )
};
$dbh->do($create_query);

 $create_query = qq{
     create table event(
         id_event int(10) auto_increment NOT NULL,
         event MEDIUMTEXT COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
         primary key (id_event)
         )
};
$dbh->do($create_query);
```

Now the relational table looks like this :

```
$create_query = qq{
    create table article_event_index(
        id_article int(10) NOT NULL,
        id_event int(10) NOT NULL,
        primary key (id_article, id_event),
        foreign key (id_article) references article (id_article),
        foreign key (id_event) references event (id_event)
        )
};
$dbh->do($create_query);
```

Does somebody know what should be the perl statement in order to fill 'article_event_index' table ?
For the other tables I use arrays for each table it looks like this :

```
my $i_event;
my $id_event = 0;
my @event_index;
for ($i_event = 0; $i_event < @event_prepare; $i_event++){
    $dbh->do("
        INSERT INTO `event`(`id_event`, `event`)
        VALUES ('$id_event', '$event_prepare[$i_event]')
        ") || die $dbh->errstr;
    push @event_index, $i_event;
}
$id_event++;
```

In this case the 'id_event' is generated by the increment of $id_event. Is this a good practice if I want to reuse this id in the index table ?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Dave Sherohman's response, here are a few comments on your code:

You should consider using a prepared statement for your insert:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `event`(`id_event`, `event`) VALUES (?,?)");
```

Then in your loop you can just do this for each row you need to insert:

```
$sth->execute($id_event, $event_prepare[$i_event]);
```

This is simpler (it handles the quoting for you), safer (prevents SQL injection), and faster.

In addition, you never need to use C-style for loops just for going through an array.  You can use one of these forms:

```
for my $i_event (0..$#event_prepare){
    #if you need the array index.
}

for my $event (@event_prepare) {
    #if you don't need the array index.
}
```

Also, this is just a preference, but I don't like `{ ... }`  as string delimiters, because they look too much like code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `id_event` field is defined as `auto_increment`, you can just let the database generate the id values for you, which is how I normally do it to avoid any chance of race conditions.  (i.e., If two separate users/processes try to insert rows at the same time and both generate the same id value, the one that commits second will fail.)

After inserting a row, you can use DBI's `last_insert_id` method to obtain the autogenerated id value for the new row if you need it for use as a foreign key in another table:

```
my $id = $dbh->last_insert_id(undef, undef, 'event', 'id_event');
```

Comment: Yes, whit 'last_insert_id' method I get the list of id's. But then how do I make the relation one-to-many between 'article' and 'event'? Because one article, may have multiple events. So it would be : 1 - 1, 1 - 2, 2 - 3, 2 - 4, 2 - 5... and so on. The first number being the article and the second the event. Thanks again

Comment: One to many relation is defined here by how you populate the table. If on your mapping table, you insert for the same even id, several article id's (which is allowed by your mapping table definition), that there you have an one-to-many relation. I feel that you're looking for a 'magical' way to create one-to-many relation without handling idx and cross tables. You should have a look at `DBIx::Class`, which lets you do so (but has a more complex API than `DBI`).